# In EXCEL: How to calculate percentage of column total, based on month chosen in drop down

Tags: excel

In Excel I want to calculate an individual line as a percent of the total column, but I would like to have a dynamic calculation so that I can calculate different columns (or in this case months) based upon a drop down month chosen.

As example in the screenshot below, the word "September" in Cell AH35 is the chosen month, so I want to calculate the percent of each row in the column titled September AC36.

I.E. what percent is .0018 of the total 21.247.  And I want this to change based upon the month chosen

Example: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have things like Dec2 and December so Cell AH35 should be a validation list using the range of headers you want this to be able to search for.   You then can use Hlookup, Row(), Offset() and Match() to achieve the results.  You will need to adjust the range T36:AE45 to match your full range. In offset the 10 is for the number of cells until the total.  The hlookup gets the value and the offset portion gets the total.  Then format the cells as percentages.  The only reason I tackled this is it looked like a nice little challenge.  You should really try something for yourself next time and post when you get stuck as we typically do not answer questions that ask us to do it for you, FYI...

Edit:  You add this to the end of the row so AH37 through AH45

```
=HLOOKUP(AH35,T36:AE45,ROW()-ROW(T36)+1,FALSE)/OFFSET(T36,10,MATCH(AH35,T36:AE36,0)-1)
```

Comment: Worked absolutely perfect.  Thanks!